# The requested package nesbot/carbon (locked at 1.31.1, required as 1.22.*)

Tags: laravel-5.5

I have this problem, when trying to install `composer require doctrine/dbal`

```
 Problem 1
    - The requested package nesbot/carbon (locked at 1.31.1, required as 1.22.*) is satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.31.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - laravel/framework v5.5.40 requires nesbot/carbon ^1.24.1 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.24.1, 1.24.2, 1.25.0, 1.26.0, 1.26.1, 1.26.2, 1.26.3, 1.26.4, 1.27.0, 1.28.0, 1.29.0, 1.29.1, 1.29.2, 1.30.0, 1.31.0, 1.31.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.40 requires nesbot/carbon ^1.24.1 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.24.1, 1.24.2, 1.25.0, 1.26.0, 1.26.1, 1.26.2, 1.26.3, 1.26.4, 1.27.0, 1.28.0, 1.29.0, 1.29.1, 1.29.2, 1.30.0, 1.31.0, 1.31.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.40 requires nesbot/carbon ^1.24.1 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.24.1, 1.24.2, 1.25.0, 1.26.0, 1.26.1, 1.26.2, 1.26.3, 1.26.4, 1.27.0, 1.28.0, 1.29.0, 1.29.1, 1.29.2, 1.30.0, 1.31.0, 1.31.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.5.40, required as 5.5.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.40].
```

I am using laravel 5.5.*

but I don't find way to satisfy this.

I tried re installing carbon, but the problem persist.

Comment: In laravel 5.7 carbon package is inbuild.